# Is 进 correct: 他喜欢进我的房间(来)和我聊天儿？

Tags: word-choice, word

```
他喜欢进我的房间(来)和我聊天儿。A website gives me another option: 他喜欢到我的房间(来)和我聊天儿.
```

It changes 进 into 到.

Is 进 correct? Or are both 进 and 到 OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

进 means 'enter'

> 他喜欢(进)我的房间(来)和我聊天儿 --> he like to (enter) my room (to) chat with me (X)

As you can see, it is not a good choice of word in English. A better wording should be  "he like to (go to) my room (to) chat with me". In Chinese, it would be

> 他喜欢(到)我的房间(来)和我聊天儿 (O)

Other example:

他喜欢(进)旅馆过夜 --> He like to (enter) hotel to spend the night (X)

他喜欢(到)旅馆(去)过夜--> He like to (go to) hotel (to) spend the night (O)

> You can use 去(go to) or 来 (come to) instead of 到, and you can omit 来(to) in Chinese

Example:

他喜欢(去/来)我的房间和我聊天儿

他喜欢(去)旅馆过夜

Answer (score 1):

Correct but 进 emphasize the action "enter" and your room space.

If you want to say your cat or a hateful person enters your room, 进 is more appropriate.

到 is a neutral word to describe the behavior.

Another word 来, 来我房间和我聊天. imply that the behaviour, enter your room, is welcomed.

他喜欢进我的房间(来)和我聊天儿